# How to achieve amazon EC2 shared volume without (or with) AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, shared

I currently have a CMS (EpiServer) system up and running on 3 EC2 Windows instances on AWS, behind a load balancer.

They are all connected to a database, so the data that is written is synchronized correctly.

**Problem**

The problem is that, if someone upload any images, the images are only uploaded to one of the EC2 instances.

So i need a way of getting a shared EBS volume between the instances that i setup.

**Tried**

I tried by using AWS SDK and Geta.AmazonS3 library, but i met some problems regarding page files virtual path provider (see unanswered: [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147288/how-to-add-a-working-aws-s3-virtualpath-provider-for-episerver-pagefiles)).

**One solution**
So i've tried to find another way to do this, and thought that i could see if there are som mounting possibilities for AWS S3. I found [TNTdrive](http://tntdrive.com/), which does the job, it mounts my S3 bucket as a windows volume, and the CMS system accepted it.

I'm just afraid that it makes unnecessary requests and the cost(price) of it(I would prefer open source :) ).

**Question:**

So my question is:
Does anybody know of an open source program that do the same, or another posibility?
I have not read too much about [AWS Storage Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/), but could that do what i need?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try the [Virtual Path Provider for S3](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Andre-Brynildsen/Dates/2011/9/Virtual-Path-Provider-for-Amazon-S3/)?

Comment: Late answer, but yes... i tried that. Met problems with "The VirtualPathProvider configured to handle page files must return directories that implement IPageDirectory" on the PageFiles VPP

Ended up using a sync tool. Going to change this to a shared network file server instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount S3 bucket onto all your 3 EC2 instances. It's a 2-way mount so all your files will be synchronized. You could use [s3f3](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) to do the mounting.

I used this guide and set up mine pretty quick: [Mount S3 onto EC2](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/03/08/how-to-mount-s3-bucket-in-linux-ec2-instance/)